# What are the CORS differences between Azure Blob Storage's primary endpoint and the default $web container?

Tags: ajax, cors, azure-blob-storage

### Scenario

I'm attempting to retrieve a JSON file via JQuery's ajax call.

### Configuration

I have the Storage Account's CORS settings configured as follows:

- allow origin: *
- methods: GET, OPTIONS
- allow headers: *
- expose headers: *.

I also have the default $web container access level set to Blob (anonymous reads for blob).

#### Blob URL Outcome

When using the blob storage URL specifying the default $web container, I can access the file:

URL: `https://my-storage.blob.core.windows.net/$web/config/version.json`

#### Primary Endpoint Outcome

When accessed through the primary endpoint, I get a 405:

URL: `https://my-storage.z20.web.core.windows.net/config/version.json`

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-storage.z20.web.core.windows.net/config/version.json' from origin 'http://localhost:7777' has been blocked by CORS policy
```

### Question

So, what's the difference here?  What am I missing?

Comment: Your CORS configuration is for blob storage, right?

Comment: Correct.  I'll update the question to make that explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you have configured CORS settings for your blob storage. Once you access the same content through static website endpoint, those CORS rules do not apply anymore as `static websites doesn't support CORS` (at least as of today).

[image]

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#viewing-content

Comment: Excellent answer!  Thanks!